# Site is Getting Cut Off on Mobiles and Tablets

Tags: mobile

I have created a non responsive design (intentionally) but find that is cutting off on the right on mobiles and tablets. I want the mobile sites to look identical to the desktop version. The url is http://wantherwardrobe.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing your site in my iPhone and it seems that you have a «mobile theme» or something. To  maintain the aspect of the site trough devices you should change this tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1290">`

to this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>`

Hope this helps